# Find the solution to the following differential equation $y'' - 4y' = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve for the solution towards the following equation and would appreciate some feedback on my approach.

$y'' - 4y' = 0$

I began  with:

$m^2-4m=0 \implies m^2-4m+2 = (m-2)^2$

Though I'm not sure where to go from here.

I have thought of: $y = c_1e^{kx} + c_2e^{-kx}$

Then plugging in the values of the quadratic above, however, this doesn't give me the solution: $c_1 + c_2^{4x}$

Comment: What do you mean by $4'$?  Do you mean $4$?  Or do you mean $y'$?  Or maybe $4y'$?

Comment: Did you mean to write $4y'$?

Comment: As for $m^2-4m=0$, that is equivalent to $m(m-4)=0$.  I do not follow what you tried to write, but it doesn't look correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve $$m^2-4m=0$$
Factorize $m$:
$$m(m-4)=0$$
$$\implies m=0 ;m=4$$
Then you get the solution
$$y=c_1e^{0x}+c_2e^{4x}$$
$$y=c_1+c_2e^{4x}$$

Comment: Thanks! this helped support me also towards my next exercise

Comment: You're welcome @Meilton

Answer (score 1):

One alternative solution from what I have seen in the answers:

Let $p = y'$ and let $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$
Substituting you get:
\begin{align*}
p' - 4p = 0 \Leftrightarrow p' = 4p 
\end{align*}
Which is a linear equation, with the following solution:
\begin{align*}
p = Ce^{\int4 dx} = Ce^{4x} , C\in \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
Note that i didn't put an extra constant as it's not necessary, since $C \in \mathbb{R}$ does the trick.
Now, and reverting the variable change made in the begining you get:
\begin{align*}
y = \frac{C}{4}e^{4x}+C_{1}
\end{align*}
with both $C$ and $C_{1} \in \mathbb{R}$